# Filling a int[] array

Tags: java, arrays, sqrt

I must make a int array filled with 5000 numbers, and then take the value of each cell, which is a random number up to 1000, and multiply it by the square root of the cell index.

So far, my code is:

```
import java.util.*;

public class thousandArray{
   public static void main (String args[]){
      int numbers[] = new int[5000];
      int r = 0 + (int)(Math.random()*1000);
      double rt = numbers[r];
      while(rt==numbers[r]){
         r=0+(int)(Math.random()*1000);
         double square = rt*Math.sqrt(numbers[r]);
         System.out.println(square);
         System.exit(0);
      }
   }
}
```

<del>im pretty sure I did the code right, I cant figure out how to fill my array.</del>

Comment: What is your goal? What actually happens?

Comment: Do you know what `System.exit(0);` does?

Comment: This loop *may* only fire once, thanks to that `System.exit(0)`.  You're not filling anything close to 5000 entries.

Comment: You never actually assign anything to any of the elements of `numbers`, so they will all remain initialized to zero.

Comment: You have to be logical and humble first. If the code doesn't do what it should do, then you shouldn't be pretty sure that you did the code right. Your code has a much higher probability to be buggy than the code of standard classes used by millions of developers.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;

public class thousandArray{
   public static void main (String args[]){
      int numbers[] = new int[5000];
      int r = 0 + (int)(Math.random()*1000);
      double rt = numbers[r]; //you never assigned anything to numbers[r]
      while(rt==numbers[r]){
         r=0+(int)(Math.random()*1000);
         double square = rt*Math.sqrt(numbers[r]);
         System.out.println(square);
         System.exit(0); //you exit the first time it loops
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried tweaking it a bit, and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

To fill an int array:

```
int[] numbers = new int[5000];
for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
    numbers[i] = some_value;
}
```

To make the values be random, more or less as the problem states, you'd use:

```
    numbers[i] = (int)(Math.random()*1000);
```

To multiply by the square root of the cell index:

```
    numbers[i] = numbers[i] * (int)Math.sqrt(i);
```

Of course, that assumes that `numbers` should be an int array.  It would make more sense for it to be a `double` array, in which case you'd remove the `(int)` casts.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ThousandArray {
    public static void main (String args[]){
        int MAX = 5000;
        int numbers[] = new int[MAX];
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
            numbers[i] = (int)(Math.sqrt(i) * (Math.random()*1000));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you plan to assign that `double` value to an `int` array element?

Comment: @HotLicks> Where exactly have I assigned a `double` to an `int`?

Comment: And what do you mean "there's no effect in ..."?  Sqrt of i will start off zero, and grow to 70, affecting the range of random values in the elements.

Comment: @HotLicks> Yes, it's right. I was considering just the effect of randomness.

Comment: Ok, you changed the problem statement -- "I must make a int array..."

Comment: @HotLicks> Next? :))))